# python Pandasで、テーブル解析後、行数が足りません。

Tags: python, pandas

Python pandasでテーブル解析しましたが、どのサイトでも行数がサイト通りに解析できません。

以下、コードです。

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://weather.time-j.net/'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
print(dfs[1].head())
```

結果です。

都市名 今日の最高気温 最高気温の平年値 今季の昨日までの記録              
   都市名 今日の最高気温 最高気温の平年値   日最高気温の最低     起日 真冬日の日数
0   札幌    8.8℃     2.5℃      -3.0℃  12月4日     5日
1   仙台   16.2℃     8.9℃       5.3℃  12月5日     0日
2   東京   15.3℃    12.5℃       7.1℃  12月7日     0日
3  名古屋   15.7℃    12.2℃       8.0℃  12月7日     0日
4   新潟   14.8℃     9.3℃       6.2℃  12月6日     0日

Answer (score 1):

```
df = dfs[1].loc[2:,:]
df.columns = ['都市名', '昨日の最高気温', '最高気温の平年値','日最高気温の最低', '起日','真冬日の日数']
```

でいかがでしょうか。
一行目のプログラムでデータフレームのデータ部分（3行目以降）のみ抽出、
二行目のプログラムで列名を再定義しております。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみます。